# How To Join with comma ONLY Lines Starting with Indent (Tab or 4 space) at Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

How can I join with comma ONLY all lines that has indent (Tab or 4 space) at beginning in NotePad++

```
analyse
    analysed
    analyser
    analysers
    analyses
    analysing
    analysis
    analyst
    analysts
    analytic
    analytical
approach
    approachable
    approached
    approaches
    approaching
    unapproachable
```

to be like

```
analyse
'analysed','analyser','analysers','analyses','analysing','analysis','analyst','analysts','analytic','analytical'
approach
'approachable','approached','approaches','approaching','unapproachable'
```

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h+(\w+)(\R?)(\w)?`
- Replace with: `'$1'(?3$2:,)$3`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(\w+)       # group 1, 1 or more word characters
(\R?)       # group 2, any kind of linebreak, optionnal
(\w)?       # group 3, optionnal, a word character
```

**Replacement:**

```
'               # single quote
$1              # content of group 1
'               # single quote
(?3             # if group 3 exists (i.e. there is a word chracter at the beginning of next line)
    $2              # add content of group 2, the linebreak
  :               # else
    ,               # add a comma
)               # endif
$3              # content of group 3
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]